# Ubuntu: tool for displaying disk activity in general and by process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, monitoring, disk-activity

My Ubuntu system is occasionally becoming very sluggish. I'm running many things simultaneously and it's very difficult to tell which program is the culprit.

I suspect that the sluggishness is due to disk activity since the CPU usage is consistently under 50% on each of the 4 cores of the CPU, and over 30% of the 6GB of RAM are free.

Is there a tool that can show me in real time the number of disk IO operations per second and the amount of data read/written per second? Can all this info be broken down and displayed per process?

Comment: I'm still hoping some day I'll find a graphical monitor, that shows some kind of graph. Windows 8 Has really impressive system monitoring capabilities in TaskManager.

Answer (score 7):

I can recommend [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/), which shows you exactly disk-read and disk-write in bytes per seconds, per process.
You can install it with `sudo apt-get install iotop` in Ubuntu.

Comment: By default, all processes are shown, but you can use "iotop --only", or hit "o" during the display, to show only processes or threads actively doing I/O. You can also limit it to processes (rather than including all threads) with the -P command-line option. Hit "a" display accumulated I/O instead of bandwidth. In this mode, iotop shows the amount of I/O processes have done since iotop started.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`atop`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/atop). Start it and press <kbd>d</kbd> to show disk-related output.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Saidar.

```
apt-get install saidar
```

[image]

Alternatively you could try one of these: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/06/list-of-best-system-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Stacer](https://oguzhaninan.github.io/Stacer-Web)

```
sudo apt install stacer
```

It looks like a good option if you want/need a graphical interface. It has many other features.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPsAo.png)